# What is ? element and how to test for it?

Tags: clojure

Calling reverse on the output of the following

```
(def seq-counter (atom 0))


(defn tokenize-data [data]
    (reduce
        (fn [out-data-map token]
            (if (seq? token)
                (conj out-data-map {(keyword (str "DIRECTIVE_" (reset! seq-counter (inc @seq-counter))))token})
                (if-not (= token (first '(EQU)))
                    (conj out-data-map {(keyword (str "DATA_1")) token})
                    (conj out-data-map {:START '(EQU)}))))
        {}
        data))
```

called with

```
'(EQU (COLOR TABLE) ?)
```

produces

```
([:START (EQU)] [:DIRECTIVE_13 (COLOR TABLE)] [:DATA_1 ?])
```

My question is: What is the ? as a value and how do I compare it (other than what is below)?

I can't seem to test to see if ? is there using \?.

All I can do is compare it like this, and I get the result I want.

```
(= (last (nth (reverse (tokenize-data '(EQU (COLOR TABLE) ?))) 2)) (first '(?)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prevent Clojure from evaluating any expression by just putting a quote `'` in front of that expression. So `'(?)` quotes a list with `?` as its first element without Clojure trying to call the `?` function, and `(first '(?))` accesses the `?` in that list.

To get at the `?` symbol directly, simply do `'?`, which will let you access the symbol itself without Clojure trying to return the value (if any) that is assigned to `?`

```
user=> (= '? (first '(?)))
true
```

Comment: Thanks. I forgot ' applies to list elements as well as the lists themselves.